# Rails: How to use a javascript slider to display ActiveRecord Objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

On my homepage, I want to display 30 random users. But I want to display them using a slider. So only 1 user is displayed at a time and there is slider to go to the next user. In my homepage controller I have:

```
@random_users = User.random(30)
```

I want to display the users photo and other information from his profile in a `div` with

```
height:400px;
width:200px;
```

I am just not sure how to implement slider functionality for active record objects. Is there a gem or a plugin that I can use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my regular choices for a slider is **bxslider**: http://bxslider.com/.

There is a rails gem **bxslider-rails** that gets it all setup for you: https://github.com/manfe/bxslider-rails

Then you can do something like this:

**View:**

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <ul class="bxslider">
    <% @random_users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= image_tag user.image %>
        <%= user.name %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({mode: 'fade', auto: true});
```

**CSS:**

```
.slider-wrapper { 
  height:400px;
  width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not gem for that but if you are using jquery then there are jQuery plugins like jCarousel and Cycle, which you can use.

Comment: Yes I found a number of plugins like http://ramblinglabs.com/slider-rails. They are all for images. Im just not sure how you can iterate through `@random_users` and display those instead of the images.

Comment: So instead of <img > tags you can put any html elements you want.